# Android Amplify- DataStoreChannelEventName RECEIVED_FROM_CLOUD no longer supported

Tags: android, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

So I updated my amplify library to the latest version and the RECEIVED_FROM_CLOUD datastore event has been removed. Is there a replacement that can be used that does the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RECEIVED_FROM_CLOUD` was an undocumented, internal event. It was removed as of [Amplify Android 1.5.0](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/releases/tag/release_v1.5.0).

Since then, we have provided [documentation for a number of public  DataStore events, here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/datastore-events/q/platform/android).

Additionally, there is a [`SUBSCRPTION_DATA_PROCESSED`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/blob/593e01d2db283e97727c4992a5729d777d045e7a/core/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/datastore/DataStoreChannelEventName.java#L50-L54) event, which will fire whenever:

> The server sent the client data over the WebSocket subscription. The data was successfully melded back into the local store.

I think that one is the most direct replacement for the old `RECEIVED_FROM_CLOUD`.

Source: I implemented and removed the original `RECEIVED_FROM_CLOUD` event.